# Euler Project 2

Tags: java, project, fibonacci

So I am not very good at it yet at all (understatement). I am trying to solve problems in the Euler project, and I am already stuck on 2.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous 2 terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Here is my code which I have repeatedly tried to fix:
(I think there is something wrong with the for loop logic.)

```
public class tesy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int fib = 0;
        int tot = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for (fib = 0; tot < 4000000; fib++) {
            tot = fib + (fib + 1);

            if (tot % 2 == 0) {
                total = tot + total;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that is very important for everyone reading your code is formatting (especially indentation). If you used an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, for example), this would be done for you automatically.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for either your age or your current knowledge in Java :). But can you explain what problem you have with your current code?

Comment: Why don't you follow the definition of the Fibonacci sequence? You are adding `fib + (fib+1)` which is just `2*fib + 1`, instead of remembering the previous Fibonacci number (not its position in the sequence!) and adding it to the current one to retrieve your new Fibonacci number.

Comment: tot = fib + (fib + 1) calculates "the sum of the previous value of 'fib' and the previous value of 'fib' plus one".   You want "the sum of the previous two fibonacci numbers".    (hint:  you'll need two variables to sum the sequence like this - the previous term, and the term before it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is erroneous in couple of ways,

```
tot = fib + (fib + 1); /** This will always be `(2*fib + 1)` and `fib` is getting 
incremented by 1 each time. You have no reference to the previous two terms of the 
sequence. **/
```

Try the below logic instead.

```
class Fibonacci
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int fiboFirst = 1;
        int fiboSecond =2;
        int fib = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while(fiboSecond < 4000000)
          {
            // This will calculate the current term of the sequence
            fib = fiboFirst + fiboSecond;  

            // Below two lines will update fib[i] and fib[i - 1] terms
            // for the next loop iteration.
            fiboFirst = fiboSecond;   // fib[i]
            fiboSecond = fib;   // fib[i -1]
            if (fib % 2 == 0)
              {
                sum = sum + fib;
              }
          }
        System.out.println(sum+2);
    }
}
```

> **Explanation**
>
> Here `fiboFirst` is equivalent to F[n] and `fiboSecond` is equivalent
>   to F[n - 1] in the Fibonacci sequence definition. In each iteration,
>   those two values should be replaced, in order to be used in the next
>   iteration. That is why I have these two lines,
>
> ```
> fiboFirst = fiboSecond;   // fib[i]
> fiboSecond = fib;   // fib[i -1]
> ```

[**HERE**](https://ideone.com/jhECQg) is the execution of the above program

Comment: the logic looks really good and far better than my own, but some of it I don't get - such as fiboSecond = fib; - could you comment on the code and why each line is there? Thanks

Comment: Ah! Now I understand - its so clear. Thanks and awesome code btw.

Comment: Thank you! :) I have edited my answer with an explanation too. Hope it helps. If my answer solves your issue you can accept it too...

Comment: Accepted and code edited - problem solved thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be following the actual equation used to generate a fibonacci sequence, therefore there is no (obvious) way of fixing your code.

```
int fibA = 1, fibB = 2, total = 0;

while(fibB <= 4000000) {
    // Add to the total, set fibA to fibB and get the next value in the sequence.
    if(fibB % 2 == 0) total += fibB;
    int temp = fibA;
    fibA = fibB;
    fibB = fibB + temp;
}
```

The above code should find the sum of all values less than or equal to 4000000

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses BigInteger. Please verify the results.

```
public class Fibonacci{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger r = fibonacciEvenSum();
        System.out.println(r);
    }

    public static BigInteger fibonacciEvenSum(){
        int f = 1;
        int s = 2;
        int mn4 = 4000000;
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

        while(s <= mn4){
            if(s % 2 == 0){
                sum = sum.add(BigInteger.valueOf(s));
            }
            f = f + s;
            s = s + f;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before writing a program like this, you should first think of what's underlying this program. You should first understand how to generate a Fibonacci series before graduating on to doing something with the series. I'll give you my solution so that you can understand.

```
class euler2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0, b = 1; /* the first elements of Fibonacci series are generally
                          thought to be 0 and 1. Therefore the series is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3... . 
                          I've initialized first and second elements such  */
        double sum = 0; // The initial sum is zero of course.
        while (b < 4000000) /* since b is the second term, it will be our control variable. 
                            This wouldn't let us consider values above 4M. */
        {
            int ob = b; // to swap the values of a and b.
            b = a + b; // generating next in the series.
            a = ob; // a is now the older value of b since b is now a + b.
            if (b % 2 == 0) // if b is even
                sum += b; // we add it to the sum
        }
        System.out.println(sum); // and now we just print the sum
    }
}
```

Hope this helped!